# How to Select Specific data on query with RIGHT JOIN statement?

Tags: sql

I am joining 2 tables using RIGHT JOIN statement. I used below query and it works good. However it still display all data whenever I tried to select specific user

```
        SELECT TBLNOTIFICATIONS.NOTIFICATION_ID, TBLNOTIFICATIONS.NOTIFICATION_TYPE, FILENAMES_LIST.LOCATION_FILENAME, TBLNOTIFICATIONS.NOTIFICATION_DATE
        FROM TBLNOTIFICATIONS
        RIGHT JOIN FILENAMES_LIST 
        ON TBLNOTIFICATIONS.NOTIFICATION_ID=FILENAMES_LIST.NOTIFICATION_ID
        WHERE TBLNOTIFICATIONS.USER_ID='JCON'
```

What should I do to select data from specific user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a sample for demonstration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filtering on the left table, so all the data of the right table will still be shown.
It is probably enough to change the query to a `LEFT JOIN` to get the results you want.
Besides that, you can use aliases to make your query more readable, like so:

```
SELECT tn.NOTIFICATION_ID, tn.NOTIFICATION_TYPE, fl.LOCATION_FILENAME, tn.NOTIFICATION_DATE
FROM TBLNOTIFICATIONS AS tn
LEFT JOIN FILENAMES_LIST AS fl
ON tn.NOTIFICATION_ID = fl.NOTIFICATION_ID
WHERE tn.USER_ID='JCON'
```

Comment: Sir I have 2 distinct columns on TBLNOTIFICATIONS AND 6 distinct columns on FILENAMES_LIST. I tried your suggested query and it returns 6 rows when i put the WHERE clause, wherein it must be 3 only. Without the WHERE clause it returns 12 rows. What's must be wrong with this?

Comment: I have found the solution sir..I added 'AND fl.user_id='JCON'' and it works perfect. Anyway Thanks for the idea :-)